# parsing a html snippret in python with BeautilfulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to parse this HTML string using BeautifulSoup. The string is

```
<address><span rel="v:address"><span dir="ltr"><span class="street-address" property="v:street-address">5015 Campbell Blvd</span>, <span class="locality"><span property="v:locality">Baltimore</span>, <span property="v:region">MD</span> <span property="v:postal-code">21236</span></span> </span></span></address>
```

I actually want to get the value `Baltimore` inside the tag `<span property="v:locality">`.

But somehow when I run the following code I can only reach up to `<span class="street-address" property="v:street-address">`. How can get the value is the tag `<span property="v:locality">`

Following is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
str = <address><span rel="v:address"><span dir="ltr"><span class="street-address" property="v:street-address">5015 Campbell Blvd</span>, <span class="locality"><span property="v:locality">Baltimore</span>, <span property="v:region">MD</span> <span property="v:postal-code">21236</span></span> </span></span></address>
soup = BeautifulSoup(str)
print(soup.address.span.span.find_all('property'))
```

output is

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''<address><span rel="v:address"><span dir="ltr"><span class="street-address" property="v:street-address">5015 Campbell Blvd</span>, <span class="locality"><span property="v:locality">Baltimore</span>, <span property="v:region">MD</span> <span property="v:postal-code">21236</span></span> </span></span></address>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
>>> target = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'property': 'v:locality'})
>>> for value in target:
        print(value.text)

Baltimore
```

Comment: If I have a list of strings with the same format, can I just give a concatenated string and get a list of locations with this method?

Comment: if your strings are in a list, I'd set up an initial `final_list = []`. Then I'd just iterate through that list of strings, and just dump each `value.text` into the final_list by doing `final_list.append(value.text)` . If that makes sense. Or if you do concatenate that strings of list into one long html string, then you'd still be ok, as the `for value in target:` essentially will iterate through those span tags

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

str_html = '''<address><span rel="v:address"><span dir="ltr"><span class="street-address" property="v:street-address">5015 Campbell Blvd</span>, <span class="locality"><span property="v:locality">Baltimore</span>, <span property="v:region">MD</span> <span property="v:postal-code">21236</span></span> </span></span></address>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(str_html, 'html.parser')
print (soup.findAll('span', {'property':'v:locality'})[0].text)
```